# C# Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties. Overloading operators

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, operators, operator-overloading

I have 2 classes with overloaded operators in a namespace called Dinero, these are the 2 classes:

First one:

```
namespace Dinero
{
    class Dollar
    {
        #region Atributos

        public Double cant;

        #endregion

        #region Constructores

        public Dollar()
        {
            this.cant = 0;
        }

        public Dollar(Double amount)
        {
            this.cant = amount;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Sobrecarga de Operadores

        public static Dollar operator +(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            Dollar devolucion = new Dollar();

            devolucion.cant = eu.cant + (dol.cant * 1.3642);

            return devolucion;
        }

        public static Dollar operator -(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            Dollar devolucion = new Dollar();

            devolucion.cant = eu.cant + (dol.cant * 1.3642);

            return devolucion;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            if (eu.cant == (dol.cant * 1.3642))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            if (eu.cant != (dol.cant * 1.3642))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Second one:

```
namespace Dinero
{
    class Euro
    {
        #region Atributos

        public Double cant;

        #endregion

        #region Constructores

        public Euro()
        {
            this.cant = 0;
        }

        public Euro(Double amount)
        {
            this.cant = amount;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Sobrecarga de operadores

        public static Euro operator +(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            Euro devolucion = new Euro();

            devolucion.cant = eu.cant + (dol.cant * 1.3642);

            return devolucion;
        }

        public static Euro operator -(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            Euro devolucion = new Euro();

            devolucion.cant = eu.cant - (dol.cant * 1.3642);

            return devolucion;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            if (eu.cant == (dol.cant * 1.3642))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
        {
            if (eu.cant != (dol.cant * 1.3642))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And when I go to the main program ( I don't know how you guys call the main file, I'd like to know since I'm a total n00b ) and I type this:

```
namespace Ejercicio_21
{
    class Ejercicio_21
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Ejercicio Nro 21";

            Euro euro00 = new Euro(1);
            Dollar dollar00 = new Dollar(1);

            Euro sumaEuros = euro00 + dollar00;
```

About the last line, the compiler says:

> Error 11  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'Dinero.Euro.operator +(Dinero.Euro, Dinero.Dollar)' and
>   'Dinero.Dollar.operator +(Dinero.Euro, Dinero.Dollar)'

I assume it has something to do with the different namespaces, but I couldn't figure it out, even using google.

This is the first question I ask here, so please, don't flame me to oblivion and please excuse my horrid English.

Note: I'm forced to keep Dollar and Euro classes in a different namespace than the main program.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated: don't user `Double` to story a currency amount. `double` and `float` are more appropriate for scientific calculations (where "pretty close" is good enough.) `decimal`, on the other hand, will ensure that your financial calculations maintain the decimal precision you need.

Comment: You can also get this error if you want to start with some pre-existing code (get pulled away into something) and don't end up giving the copied class a new name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's got nothing to do with different namespaces - it's that you've got the same operator signature declared in two places:

```
public static Dollar operator +(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
public static Euro operator +(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
```

The compiler doesn't know which one you want to call.

To be honest, I don't think adding a dollar value to a Euro value makes much sense to start with - but even beyond that, having the same operation "adding dollars to Euros" should have a single logical result type.

If you *really* want to make the two operations valid, I'd suggest having instance methods called `Plus`:

```
// In Dollar
public Dollar Plus(Euro eu)

// In Euro
public Dollar Plus(Dollar dol)
```

Then:

```
Euro euro00 = new Euro(1);
Dollar dollar00 = new Dollar(1);

Euro sumaEuros = euro00.Plus(dollar00);
```

Pretty much as clear, but without the ambiguity.

Another alternative which I *don't* recommend is to make (say) the first operand's type take priority:

```
public static Dollar operator +(Dollar dol, Euro eu)    
public static Euro operator +(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
```

Then you could do:

```
Dollar dol1 = ...;
Euro eu1 = ...;

Dollar dol2 = dol1 + eu1;
Euro eu2 = eu1 + do1;
```

It's pretty horrible though.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Do I have to choose one of the two classes to place the operator-overloadings?

Comment: @Cristian: You can put operators in both classes, but it doesn't make sense to have two operators with *the same signature*.

Comment: Thank you, but my teacher is forcing us to overload operators this way. Your method is clearly better, but I'll have to stick to overloading the operators.

Comment: @Cristian: Then you'll need to give them different signatures. It's still a bad idea to even have add operations for these types, IMO...

Comment: Nice... I'll try that horrible method... my teacher will love something like that, hahaha

Comment: I just got a response from my teacher and they told me that the "official" method they suggest is the "horrible one". Thanks to God I found this site where I can learn from the best programmers :).

Comment: @Cristian: I can see if I can find anything in the C# language specification recommending that addition operators are commutative, if you like :) It may not be there, but I expect it is...

Comment: Let's keep comments for constructive criticism of the answer - not for speculative discussions about intent of comments please.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the fact that you declared

```
public static Your_Type operator +(Euro eu, Dollar dol)
```

in both classes.
So your compiler don't know which one use...

Comment: First of all, thank you. Do I have to choose one of the two classes to place the operator-overloadings?

Comment: @Cristian: Jon Skeet already gave you the best answer (as usual) :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue in VS 2015 by deleting duplicated code that was in both a project as well as a nuGet package. By unloading the project that had the duplicated code, the error went away.